# How to get a function args when I hooked it in a php7.0 exetension

Tags: php, php-internals

I tried to write a php extension to get function args. 

`<?php system('ls');?>`

In this example is 'ls'.
I hooked this function with zend_set_user_opcode_handler, and the function codes are.

```
PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(hello)
{   
    zend_set_user_opcode_handler(ZEND_DO_ICALL, do_fcall_handle);
    return SUCCESS;
}

static int do_fcall_handle(ZEND_OPCODE_HANDLER_ARGS){

return ZEND_USER_OPCODE_DISPATCH;
}
```

The PHP version is 7.2.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php7, use EG(current_execute_data)->call to get arg name and value.

```
static int do_fcall_handle(ZEND_OPCODE_HANDLER_ARGS){

    zend_string *funcName = EG(current_execute_data)->call->func->common.function_name;
    php_printf("[!] Hooked `%s`, ",ZSTR_VAL(funcName));

    int arg_count = EG(current_execute_data)->call->This.u2.num_args;
    for(int i=0; i<arg_count; i++){
        php_printf("arg%d is `%s`, ", i+1, ZSTR_VAL((EG(vm_stack_top)-(i+1))->value.str) ); 
    }
    php_printf("HOOK end;\n");
    return ZEND_USER_OPCODE_DISPATCH;
}
```